# Unable to resolve a cookbook from artifactory with a Policyfile chef install

Tags: artifactory, chef-policyfile

I am trying to use a Policyfile to configure an Artifactory repo as the source for a cookbook. I am using manual upload / curl to publish the cookbook to a `/chef` repo in artifactory (this is new too) - i wasn't able to publish with stove and want to avoid knife-art for now. The `chef install` run fails.

I am not sure if it's a fault with the upload or the chef install, and am not getting debug info from chef.

*cookbook upload*

`curl --user "myuser:API_KEY" --data-binary @mycookbook.tar.gz -X PUT https://my-artifactory-server/artifactory/chef/mycookbook.tar.gz`
I have also tried adding it to `/chef/mycookbook/mycookbook.tar.gz`. There are no versions in the path or artifact name, but the metadata is valid. Are  versions required?

*Policyfile.rb*

```
default_source :artifactory, "https://my-artifactory-server/artifactory/chef"
cookbook 'mycookbook'
run_list 'mycookbook::default'
```

I have tried with `/artifactory/api/chef/` and `/artifactory/api/chef/chef` as the URI too. ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY variable is set to my user API key.

From a directory with the policyfile, I run `chef install -D` - not much info from debugging, but this is the output i get.

```
$ chef install --debug
Building policy mypol
Expanded run list: recipe[mycookbook::default]
Caching Cookbooks...
Error: Failed to generate Policyfile.lock
Reason: (Solve::Errors::NoSolutionError) Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `mycookbook (>= 0.0.0)` required by `user-specified dependency`
```

Have tried looking through the Artifactory logs to get an idea of what might be wrong, but not seeing much - requests.log shows a GET on `/artifactory/api/chef/chef/universe` which returns an OK with `{}` for the body - so assuming the cookbook isn't being added to a cookbook listing of some sort? Artifactory version is 5.10.

I have tried adding a virtual repo that serves the "chef" local repo and update policyfile with that, but get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually got `knife artifactory` working to see how it uploads. My pathing was wrong, and uploading directly to `/artifactory/chef` with the PUT doesn't reflect in universe.

for Curl, excluding auth params:

```
-X POST https://artifactory-server/artifactory/api/chef/REPO/api/v1/cookbooks/COOKBOOK.tgz?category=CAT -H "content-type: application/x-binary" --data-binary @yourcookbookarchive.tgz
```

Comment: The `POST` is inferred, but have it explicitly here for reference.